# Appending a link title as a query parameter in the url once redirected to a new page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url

I have a table where several names are their own links and once clicked, it redirects to my landing page.

```
<a href="#/landing"><span>{{ link.linktitle }}</span></a>
```

That part works fine.

However, I need the url to look like this once redirect to the landing page:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/landing/?=link={link title}
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

PS. I also need to grab the link title from the query param and have it display somewhere on the landing page.

Thanks!

Comment: Angular 1 or angular2? :)

You could try :
`<a href="#/landing/?=link={{link.linktitle}}"><span>{{ link.linktitle }}</span></a>`

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm using good ol' Angular 1 lol. Thanks you let me give that a try.

Comment: Sweet it worked!!! Thanks so much

Comment: You are welcome, I'd suggest using somethig like jsFiddle for quick tryouts while learning:
http://jsfiddle.net/timriley/5DMjt/

The angular reference can also help:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api

Happy coding and please accept the answer :)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If the value you want to have is stored in the JS side under `link.linktitle`, your code has to look like this:

```
<a href="#/landing/?=link={{ link.linktitle }}">
    <span>{{ link.linktitle }}</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Any idea how I could grab the link title from the query param and have it display somewhere on the landing page? I'm thinking a heading where it says "Welcome {link title} and changes depending on which link has been clicked

Comment: @ChrisEM you can use `$location`for that.

Check this jsFiddle:
http://web.archive.org/web/20130317065234/http://jsfiddle.net/PHnLb/7/

You can use `($location.search()).link`.
But your url should look different, more exactly: `#/landing/?link:{{ link.linktitle }}`
Please create another question for this; it's a different story :)

Comment: Thank you @Ovi that resource was actually very helpful!

Comment: @ChrisEM Please accept the answer if it helped you :)